# How to correct segmentation fault with char * to int conversion

Tags: c, loops, fault

ive written the following as a program in order to convert a pointer with a sequence of integers as its adress into an integer number:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *recepcao() { char *receber;
    scanf("%s", receber);
    return receber;
}
int conversao(char *string) { int i, j;
    for(i=0; string[i]!='\0'; ++i) {
        continue;
    }
    int *var;
    int contagem=0;
    for(j=0; j<i-1; ++j) {
        var[j]=(string[j]-'0');
        contagem+=var[j]*pow(10, (i-j-1));
    }

    return contagem;
}
int main() {
    printf("%i", conversao(recepcao())); return 0;
}
```

I've tried about a thousand times to correct all the loops, but still after recieving the scanf value the program would crash, as stated on some IDEs, and would display a "Segmentation Fault: 11" message on others. How can I fix this? what is the proper definition of that message?

Comment: Undefined behavior. I am counting on how many cases it is UB now.

Comment: what does `receber` point to?

Comment: You've got a memory allocation problem.  Your pointers don't point to memory properly allocated for the strings you're trying to store.

Comment: You really should consider properly naming variables and functions with actual complete words. This is incredibly hard to read because your naming scheme is hard to parse.

Comment: You need to alocate moemory and use `char *receber` to point there. @coderredoc Are you still counting ? :))

Comment: @BenWainwright I assume those names are meaningful in Spanish or Portuguese.

Comment: @SteveSummit oh right. In which case they should be translated to English: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange

Comment: @Michi.: It seems I was doing better when counting.

Comment: receber points to receiving the string through scanf

Comment: @PedroSecchi.: [**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) would (definitely) help you.

Comment: @SteveSummit thanks yeah thats right! its portuguese

Comment: I was just beginning with pointers, sorry if the question was unclear or else impertinent. thanks for the reference though.

Comment: @BenWainwright sorry, I've created my account like seconds ago and Im not entirely used to conventions.

Comment: Ive read some more topics on pointers just to find out how much Im a c elephant dancing on eggs  for now, but thanks for the patience though, you've been great. Ive been learning about half an hour a day through the internet before my classes start... so IE thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing pointers with arrays. A pointer just points; declaring a pointer does not reserve memory, it just creates a pointer variable pointing to some undefined place.

Corrected program:

```
char *recepcao(char *receber) {
    scanf("%s", receber);
    return receber;
}
int conversao(char *string) { int i, j;
    for(i=0; string[i]!='\0'; ++i) {
        continue;
    }
    int var[100];
    int contagem=0;
    for(j=0; j<i-1; ++j) {
        var[j]=(string[j]-'0');
        contagem+=var[j]*pow(10, (i-j-1));
    }

    return contagem;
}
int main() {
    char receber[100];
    printf("%i", conversao(recepcao(receber))); return 0;
}
```

Update:

Arrays and pointers are used in a very similar manner in C, but they are not the same. When you declare an array, the compiler reserves the required memory:

```
int a[10], b[10];
a[1] = 1;  // OK
a = b;     // Error!
```

Element of array is variable, but array name is **not**. Array name is sort of label, you cannot change its value so that it pointed to another array.

Pointer **is** variable. When you declare a pointer, the compiler creates it with undefined contents (like any other variable).

```
int *p, *q;
p = q;      // OK but useless because both the pointers contain junk addresses
a[0] = *p;  // Depending on where p points you will get either junk in a[0] or memory access violation
. . . 
p = a;                 // Now you can use p as a synonym for array a declared above
if (*(p + 1) == a[1])  // Always true
if (p[2] == *(a + 2))  // Always true
. . .
b = p;   // This won't work; can't assign a new value to array name b
. . .
q = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10); // Another way of creating int array of 10 elements
q = p;  // Array created with malloc is lost because nothing points to it now
```

Basically, the only difference between pointers and arrays is that pointer is variable and array name is not. You can't write "a = p" exactly as you can't write "2 = i".

There also is a rather confusing quirk with array as a formal argument:

```
   void xyz(int a[10]) {
       . . .
   }

   void main() {
       int b[20];
       . . .
       xyz(b);
   }
```

Looks like we assign b to a, and change array size, right? No, "int a[10]" is treated as "int *a", and sizeof(a) will return the size of the pointer, not the size of the array.

Comment: Right, I have fixed it.

Comment: It's still not correct, `recepcao` can overflow the buffer and you don't check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: @freim Okay, you've fixed that problem, so I'm removing my first comment and my downvote, but there are still things here that can be improved, as Pablo's comment suggests.

Comment: Ive read some more topics on pointers just to find out how much Im a c elephant dancing on eggs  for now, but thanks for the patience though, you've been great. Ive been learning about half an hour a day through the internet before my classes start...

Comment: @Steve Summit Yes, that's right, but I wanted to make as little change to the original program as possible, not to provide production-level code. The purpose was to explain the concept, and that required a certain level of simplification.

Comment: @Pedro Secchi I have extended my answer with pointer vs. arrays explanation, hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

`receber` is an uninitialized pointer. `scanf` expects a `char*` where the read characters will be written down. But in your case it points to some memory that you are not supposed to access. Trying to access it is undefined behavior. In your case it results in segmentation fault.

Among many some solutions would be to use `char receber[MAXLEN+1]` or `char * receber = malloc(MAXLEN+1)`. There is a case here now. The first solution will result in an array which is of automatic storage duration - long story short, when the function ends it will point to some memory that will be invalid - *so you can't return it* (if you use first solution).

Second solution will allocate memory dynamically which will have storage duration beyond the scope of this function. *This will be the correct one to use in this case.*

For `var` in other function you can use dynamic memory allocation or VLA support if you have one. You should allocate memory of size equal to the length of the string. Here it doesnt stop at allocation - you need to initialize it with values so that you can use it in arithmetic operation like you did. (Using it uninitialized again is undefined behavior)

For your information there is a function named `strlen` which gives you the length of a string (nul terminated char array) - use it here.

Also if you check the reference manual or man pages you will see `pow` returns double - so here in case you will face some precision issues. For calculating integral power use custom functions - it is better in case of  precision and avoiding nasty precision errors.

Comment: You could also explain to the OP that `pow()` return is `double`

Comment: `contagem += var[j] * pow(10, (i-j-1));` the way how the code looks like, `var` is used uninitialized.

Comment: @Michi.: Yes OP has to initialize it and allocate.

Comment: There is no need to use a pointer there in the first place, even if it was an actual array or `malloc`ed pointer, the OP is not using the old values in any way. It would be better to just declare `char var`.

Comment: @Pablo.: True..writing the whole thing (even this much) took me two cigar and all that . There is too many issues to consider. I chose the brutal ones only.

Comment: Yes, I tried to address all things that I've noticed in my address, hope I didn't miss anything.

Answer (score 0):

Several problems here

```
char *recepcao() { 
    char *receber;
    scanf("%s", receber);
    return receber;
}
```

has 2 errors: `receber` is an uninitialized pointer, it's pointing to nowhere in
particular, so passing to `scanf` is an undefined behaviour.

Also `receber` is a local variable of `recepcao` and it ceases to exists when
`recepcao` returns, so you are returning a pointer to invalid memory location.

It would be better that you declare an array in `main` and pass that array (with its size) to the functions. I also would use `fgets` instead of `scanf`, it easier to control `fgets`.

You can use `strlen(string)` instead of

```
for(i=0; string[i]!='\0'; ++i) {
        continue;
}
```

but that's ok if you are not allowed to use `strlen` in your assignment.

Also using `pow` is overkill here, there is no need to include floating point
arithmetic (`pow` returns a `double`) when you could use a variable `exp` initialized to 1 and multiply
it by 10 in every loop (see my code below).

Also

```
int *var;
...
for(j=0; j<i-1; ++j) {
    var[j]=(string[j]-'0');
    ...
```

is not going to work because `var` is not initialized. There is no need to use a
pointer here anyway, not even an array, you are not doing anything with the
saved values. It would be better to use a single `char` variable:

```
char var;
...
for(j=0; j<i-1; ++j) {
    var = string[j] - '0';
    ...
```

So you can rewrite your program with this information like this:

```
#include <ctype.h>

char *recepcao(char *receber, size_t len) {
    if(fgets(receber, len, stdin) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not read from user\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // removing newline
    receber[strcspn(receber, "\n")] = 0;

    return receber;
}

int conversao(const char *string) { 
    if(string == NULL)
        return 0;

    size_t len = strlen(string);

    int res = 0, pow = 1;

    for(size_t i = len - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if(isdigit(string[i]))
        {
            res += (string[i] - '0') * pow;
            pow *= 10;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "'%s' contains non-digits\n", string);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return res;
}

int main(void)
{
    char line[100];

    if(recepcao(line, sizeof line) == NULL)
        return 1;

    printf("%d\n", conversao(line));

    return 0;
}
```